# required files to distribute a .net application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to figure out what files are needed when I distribute an application that I have written. In the release folder after I have built the application I have the following:

> app.exe (obviously needed)
>
> app.exe.config (obviously needed for
>   my config settings)
>
> app.pdb
>
> app.vshost.exe
>
> app.vshost.exe.config
>
> app.vshost.exe.manifest

Answer (score 4):

- app.exe is needed
- app.exe.config is needed

The others are not needed:

- app.pdb is debugging info, which will reveal internals of your code. You should not distribute it.
- app.vshost.exe.* are visual studio debug host files, which should not be distributed.

Comment: While you shouldn't distribute app.pdb, it can be useful to save it somewhere, in case the application crashes and you need debugging info from user's reports.

Answer (score 0):

Both ClickOnce and Deployment projects tend to take care of including everything necessary.  These also take care of installing the appropriate version of the framework.